# DBeaver не подключается к mysql

Tags: mysql, база-данных, ubuntu

При попытке подключить к базе данных через DBeaver, выходит ошибка:

```
Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
  Connection refused (Connection refused)
  Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

Но если я подключаюсь через node.js, то ошибок никаких нет.

В чём может быть проблема?

Вот скриншот настроек DBeaver:
[image: Скриншот настроек DBeaver]

Comment: Думаю, сервер базы данных не запущен или недоступен для подключения из-за неправильно настроенного файервола или блокировки порта.

Comment: То есть у вас запущен локальный сервер mySQL на стандартном порту 3306, к которому вы можете подключиться из локального приложения на node.js, но не работает подключение только через DBeaver?  Проверьте/сравните настройки подключения в node.js.

Comment: Как оказалось, DBeaver не поддерживает подключение к mysql на том же компьютере на котором запущен mysql

Comment: А подключение к адресу 127.0.0.1?

Answer (score 0):

Как оказалось, DBeaver не поддерживает подключение к mysql на том же компьютере на котором запущен mysql